# Bitcoin Charts API Data

Tags: api, exchange-rate, charts

So I'm trying to learn how to work with an api, and how to get bitcoin historical price data.  Ideally, I'd like all of it, and the nice [gui that they have on the site](http://www.bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#rg60ztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv) for displaying the charts (but I don't suppose I can get the gui?).

Alternatively, I'd like to be able to just see the last 2000 trades, up to an end date, as it seems to say I can [here](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/), using http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=SYMBOL[&end=UNIXTIME].  This works fine for UNIXTIME up to a couple days ago, but not further back.  Is it possible to retrieve older data?  Or are there better ways to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a *start* and an *end* that can be quoted, and only one is required although both can be used.

If you want US$ per BTC data from a 24th April until now until now, use:

http://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=mtgoxUSD&start=1366784293

If you want all US$ per BTC data until now, use:

http://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=mtgoxUSD&start=1279424500

If you want all US$ per BTC data until 24th April 2013,:

http://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=mtgoxUSD&start=1279424500&end=1366784293